# Android simple program run error

Tags: android

I have just installed `Android SDK` to my `Eclipse`, but when I run a simple program on `Eclipse` I get following error.

```
[2012-05-02 11:15:11 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: and.
[2012-05-02 11:15:11 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2012-05-02 11:15:11 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

I added `ADT plugin` to `Eclipse` and also set path for `Android SDK` as

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ganesh\android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk-windows
```

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks

Ganesh.

Comment: For your problem try this link http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122513/emulator-error-hint-use-foo-to-launch-a-virtual-device-named-foo

Comment: If ur problem persist ... check google.com for this error .. is pretty   common error .

Answer (score 3):

Android sdk path can't contain any spaces.So your path
`C:\Documents and Settings\ganesh\android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk-windows` is wrong.
Put your sdk in a path like c:\android-sdk that containes no space.

Answer (score 0):

I second   Rasel, another workaround is changing the "SDK Location" in the Android Preferences in Eclipse to its corresponding 8dot3 directory name, As here "Documents and Settings" is causing the problem, change it to its corresponding 8dot3 directory name, that would probably be `DOCUME~1` so the comple path would be

> C:\DOCUME~1\ganesh\android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk-windows

---

If you don't know the 8dot3 name of your desired path, just use command prompt and execute "DIR /X"

Answer (score -1):

Its a very commmon issue and a bug with Android SDK. "Documents and Settings" have spaces and it breaks it.

You have 2 options

1. Re-Install SDK and avoid having spaces in the folders.
2. instead of `Documents and Settings` replace it with `DOCUME~1` if not then `DOCUME~2` (some dos path)

e.g. `C:\DOCUME~1\ganesh\android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk-windows`

I hope you'd like the secound option as you don't have to re-install SDK again. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks to all My problem is solved as i removed space from sdk path

Comment: @Sanjay thanks for pointing it out. Usual installation path is program files. datz why I was mistaken. anyway corrected the answer.